# uniqueness of composite id with null component

Tags: sql, grails, unique, grails-orm, constraints

I am running into problems using unique constraints.
The following combinations are allowed

```
A.name  B.name
foo     NULL
foo     bar
foo     bar1
foo1    bar
```

It should not be possible to create a new A with same name, only if it has a different B.
With the constraints below it is possible to create

```
A.name B.name
foo    NULL
foo    NULL
```

Because NULL seems not to have effect on unique.

Any hints how to fix this?

```
class A {
  String name
  static belongsTo = [b:B]
  static constraints = {
    name(unique:'b')
    b(nullable:true)
  }
}

class B {
  String name
  static hasMany = [as:A]
  name(unique:true)
}
```

Comment: Which RDBMS(s) are you using?

Comment: mysql, but the question aimes to be solved in grails and its constraint for domains

Comment: null values int key component can lead you to serious trouble: please consider not to allow null value in key component. Seriously : consider not to allow null value in key component

Answer (score 1):

In the database structure, could you set the columns to `NOT NULL DEFAULT 0` or similar, and then treat the zeros the same as you otherwise would the NULLs?  Since the column is for names, there's likely to be no digits in the values anyway right?

Comment: Some (or at least one, Oracle) RDBMS treat `''` as `null`.

Comment: What do the above class definitions translate to in SQL?  Could we see the table definitions, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think this will work:

```
name(unique:['b', 'name'])
```

Looking at the code for the unique constraint, it seems feasible. The constraint definitely lets you pass in a list of things to compare the uniqueness to. It calls this the uniquenessGroup. Then, when validating, it iterates over this list. Take a look starting at line 137 here: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/validation/UniqueConstraint.java.html

The code looks like this:

```
    if(shouldValidate) {
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria( constraintOwningClass )
        .add( Restrictions.eq( constraintPropertyName, propertyValue ) );
    if( uniquenessGroup != null ) {
        for( Iterator it = uniquenessGroup.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            String propertyName = (String) it.next();
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq( propertyName,
                  GrailsClassUtils.getPropertyOrStaticPropertyOrFieldValue(target, propertyName)));
        }
    }
    return criteria.list();
}
```

So it depends on whether the GrailsClassUtils.getPropertyOrStaticPropertyOrFieldValue call will retrieve a property in the same class. Which based on the name it seems like it should.

I'm curious to know if it works for you.

Comment: No that don't work. It is still possible to create two As with the same name and NULL as B